# Fastest way to check C# BitArray for non-zero value

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, collision, bitarray

I'm trying to rapidly detect collisions between BitArrays in C# (using the AND boolean operation), which results in a single BitArray representing the overlapping region.

Obviously, if the resulting array only consists of zeroes, there is no collision. What is the fastest way to check this? Simple iteration is too slow. I don't care where collisions are, or how many there are--only that there's a nonzero value somewhere in the array.

It seems like there should be some sort of fast case along the lines of "cast the entire bit array to an int value" (which specifically won't work because BitArrays are variable size), but I can't figure one out.

Comment: Have you considered not using BitArrays and just using ints instead?

Comment: If you implement this yourself, you can also avoid computing the entire intersection in the case that there is a collision, and no space is required to store the intersection. `BitArray` is a fairly slow implementation anyway.

Comment: Good ideas from everyone. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need the resulting BitArray of the And() method? If not, you could just loop through the input arrays and return true on the first collision.

```
bool collision(BitArray a1, BitArray a2) {
   if (a1 == null || a2 == null) throw new ArgumentException("arguments cannot be null");
   if (a1.Count != a2.Count) throw new ArgumentException("arrays don't have same length");
   for (int i = 0; i < a1.Count; i++)
       if (a1[i] && a2[i]) return true;

   return false;
}
```

This way you an prevent looping the Array twice -- ie. once for the And() and once for checking. In average you will traverse only half of the array once, thus speed things up to 4 times.

Another way is. like @itsme86 suggested use ints instead of BitArrays

```
int a1, a2;
bool collision = (a1 & a2) > 0;
```

Comment: I would suggest `(a1 & a2) != 0`, giving you 32 usable bits instead of only 31.

Comment: I would suggest using `Enumerable.Zip(a1, a2, (l, r) => l & r).All(x => x > 0)`.

Comment: @harold: good point, depending on the number of needed bits, one could also use UInt64

Comment: @Aron god no. The whole point of this question was efficiency.

Comment: @Aron there are some problems with your snippet: 

1. BitArray does not implement `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable` thus cannot be used with `Enumerable.Zip`  

2. The items of BitArrays are booleans, thus `All(x => x>0)` does not compile

Comment: @harold Nope. The point of the question was speed. It is relatively easy to throw in good old fashioned Parallelization...

Comment: @Aron sure, you can do it slow and then make it parallel - but you can also it fast and *still* make it parallel. No point in making is slow intentionally.

Comment: @harold I'd also like to see where you get the "its slow" from...remember it is JITed after all..

Comment: @Aron because it's JITed to slow code. LINQ does that. Nice to write one-liners in, not good for performance.

Comment: @harold The code that I gave should only be different in that there are more function calls and v-lookups. If the JITer did its job correctly then it should inline those function calls. Therefore I ask again, where is your evidence of slowness?

Comment: @Aron and a third problem: It does not fulfill the original task, because -- if it would compile -- it checks whether ALL items are collisions.

Comment: @Aron sure, hopefully it does a half decent job, making it not as bad as it could have been. As for evidence, you are not presenting any either, so where does that leave us. You've checked this sort of thing before, no doubt, so have I and so have others. The results are always the same. LINQ will lose to a plain `for` loop.

Comment: @derpirscher Sorry...I meant `.Any()`

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is still searching for a nice solution, since it's missing here:

Bitarrays initialize with zeros, so you could simply compare a fresh BitArray (of the same length) with your AND-result of the two BitArrays (Note the "!", inverting the bool...):

```
if (!new BitArray(bitCountOfResult).Equals(result)) {
    // We hit!
}
```

Fast and works for me. Make sure to avoid the LINQ-approach, it's very slow.